# Ocean modifier with Displace Geometry makes the mesh move up and down

Tags: animation, modifiers, ocean-simulation

In [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49199/water-ripples-waves-on-the-surface-of-an-object), I am trying to find how to make a simple sphere display small wavelets and ripples to make it look like it's made out of water and subject to tides / wind effect.

One of the effects that the Ocean modifier with Geometry set to "Displace" has on a mesh, is that the object will move up and down, like this:

[image]

I understand why it makes the mesh move up and down when the settings are set to "Generate" since it tries to recreate waves and tides (sorta) but here I'm trying to use this modifier to modify a mesh's surface, not to make it move.

Can I use the Ocean modifier this way and have the mesh it's applied to stay "still" or at least not move up and down so much on the Z axis?

Here's the .blend:

[image]

Comment: Would a *wave modifier* be suitable with the z axis disabled in place of the ocean modifier? I believe the ocean modifier will always move along the z axis, then again it's not one I use often myself.

Comment: Duarte's answer [on this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49199/water-ripples-waves-on-the-surface-of-an-object) is a better way to do it.