# How to make the ocean modifier to deform an object, but don't move it?

Tags: modifiers, ocean-simulation

After using the ocean modifier with an object (in displace mode), the object is floating in space. How can I make ocean modifier to deform it, but don't move it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50078/ocean-modifier-with-displace-geometry-makes-the-mesh-move-up-and-down

Comment: @fabriced Yes, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is deforming it, but the result is probably not matching the scale of your object. Try to reduce the Size parameter and maybe also the Scale parameter of the Ocean modifier.

Answer (score -1):

Apply SCALE to the object (so that x, y and z scale are all 1).