# How to create a water man?

Tags: animation, rigging, particles, physics, fluid-simulation

I need to make an animated man made out of water.

Water should be dynamic (so it must flow smoothly, keeping body shape). Drops of water should drain away from the human body and dripping on the floor. And this model should be animated (this person should move).

Something like this (but more photorealistic) https://youtu.be/WruTNnF6Ztg?t=40s

Any ideas? Maybe there are tutorials, using which it is possible to create something like this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not sure how to answer that. You could try making a fluid simulation with several emitters and make a hollow mesh of a man with a translucent material. For the water drops falling out you could probably set up a particle system. Unfortunately, I doubt anyone will explain how they found out how to do exactly what you want. Sometimes it's better to ask questions like "how can I animate water in complex shapes" and apply what you're told to solve the problem.

Comment: Not sure how that wasmade, probably using a mesh as a force field to attrack the fluid to it's surface. Perhaps start by learning more basic fluid simulations and then gradually advance until your reach that level of complexity Try this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49199/water-ripples-waves-on-the-surface-of-an-object/49216#49216 or this https://www.google.com/search?q=blender+fluid+simulation&tbm=vid also check the Blender Manual https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/fluid/index.html

Comment: @SilverRain Thank you, i will be more precise in future questions.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thank you very much for the links!