# How to make a sort of shockwave on the skin

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation, soft-body

Like you might have seen by watching television or youtube, someone getting punched or something being thrown to him/her, but I want to know how I could make the sort of "shockwave" of the skin, getting impacted, I just thought about maybe soft bodies while writing the last sentence but i'm not sure, kinda new to blender

Comment: I have done this (less than well) using bones to drive small portions of the skin. I need this same effect, and will watch this answer. Unique bones work well for shaking and twitching motions (reactions to fly bites, for example)  but I have not been skillful in created the sort of skin surface reactions you would get from deer or sheep  head-butting one another, for example. Post whatever you get as ideas!

Comment: You could experiment with dynamic paint (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/dynamic_paint/index.html) and displacement.

Comment: Read a bit of it and I believe it would be Wave Type?

Comment: I can't even get the damn Dynamic paint to work on a plane  :'(

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49199/water-ripples-waves-on-the-surface-of-an-object

Comment: So from searching a bit (after months that  is) I found that the way of doing: to have a lattice use Soft body with some settings Pinned so it doesnt move, assign the lattice modifier to the body/thing you want to have that effect, assign the area you want the effect to have on in a vert group and make the lattice modifier use that group, have something impact the lattice and that's it, with some tweaks you can have the result you want