# How can I randomise a texture that is being used in a displacement modifier?

Tags: animation, texturing, modifiers, displacement

I am trying to create a stop motion look using a displacement modifier that subtly alters the object each frame, but I cannot find a way to simply randomise the seed of the voronoi texture. I feel like I am missing something obvious, as I cannot even locate a way to edit the texture aside from in the properties tab.

Is there a way to randomise a generated texture that isn't being used in a material?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49199/water-ripples-waves-on-the-surface-of-an-object/49216#49216

Comment: As Duarte recommends, you can use an empty as Coordinates in your Displace modifier, if you move, rotate and scale this empty it will move the Voronoi, it's not exactly like the W value of the Noise Texture, but you can come pretty close to this effect, as if the texture was evolving randomly