# Manipulate shader based off moving geometry relative to camera

Tags: scripting, shaders, faces, shader-nodes

My intention is to write a shader that will most closely resemble how motion in claymation looks. Specifically, for example, when a character moves their hand, you can see slight abnormalities in the surface texture of the moving part of the mesh, while the rest of the motionless body stays exactly the same.

I have found easy ways to get a nice texture on the mesh and randomize it every frame to give it variation, but I have yet to find a way to discriminate between moving parts of the mesh and static parts.

Furthermore, as I intend to use this to replicate a hand-drawn 2D look rather than a 3D clay look, it would also be ideal for the object's relative position in the camera view to also be taken into account. For instance, a hand-drawn character has to be redrawn entirely if the camera position changes because the perspective changes. Therefore, if the object's position in the camera view changes.

TLDR; is there a way to adjust a random noise factor on a textured object only for faces that move *relative to the camera view* between frames?

Is there any way to do this, whether that be through the traditional shader editor or scripting?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49199/water-ripples-waves-on-the-surface-of-an-object/

Comment: The easiest thing to do would probably be to use some noise textures to displace the geometry in the geometry node editor

Comment: I second what @BrodieLobins said. Except I don't think you'd even need to do this in geometry nodes. I think it would work just by using a displace modifier with a noise texture. When the object data changes, the displacement will update. If it isn't moving, the displacement will remain fixed.

Comment: The noise texture certainly adds some variation to the mesh, but what I'm looking for is more of a color-based difference, like in a shader. I think this would be possible by doing some fancy stuff with the normals. Additionally, the noise displacement updates on every face for every frame, which is not what I want. I only want the noise to update for faces that move relative to the camera from frame to frame.

Comment: Use something like musgrave or voronoi, that stays constant between faces/frames