# Using the Ocean modifier on a cylinder

Tags: mesh, uv, modifiers, normals, ocean-simulation

**I want to use the ocean modifier to displace a cylinder evenly, is there a way to do that?** The best I got was for it to work but projected on a single axis, where the "front" is displaced correctly, but the sides are plain and the back is inverted.

[image: Front]

[image: Side]

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [mapping ocean to a sphere](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2877/935). [This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/49199/935) may also be helpful.